# Need to Simplify iOS swift NSLayoutConstraint VisualFormat

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am new  to `NSLayoutConstraintVisualFormat` . Please find the code below to achieve the design shown below.

[image]

Please find the code below

**Code Snippet :**

```
func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }


    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-1-[v0]-1-|", views: topBorderView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-1-[v0(40)]-1-|", views:topBorderView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-[v1(80)]-8-|", views: nameLabel,codeLabel)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: nameLabel)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: codeLabel)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0]|", views: flag)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-55-[v0]|", views: flag)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: flag, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 50))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: flag, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0, constant: 50))

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-80-[v0(75)]|", views: placeholder)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-50-[v0(30)]|", views: placeholder)


    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-165-[v0(1)]|", views: seperatorView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-60-[v0(45)]|", views: seperatorView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-200-[v0(75)]|", views: placeholder1)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-50-[v0(30)]|", views: placeholder1)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-80-[v0(75)]|", views: buyingPriceLabel)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-80-[v0(30)]|", views: buyingPriceLabel)


    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-200-[v0(75)]|", views: sellingPriceLabel)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-80-[v0(30)]|", views: sellingPriceLabel)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-80-[v0(195)]|", views: lastUpdatedDate)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-120-[v0(30)]|", views: lastUpdatedDate)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-0-[v0(290)]|", views: thirtyDaysUpdateButton)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-150-[v0(40)]|", views: thirtyDaysUpdateButton)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-250-[v0(35)]|", views: buttonRightImage)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-152-[v0(35)]|", views: buttonRightImage)
```

Comment: I would suggest to do the same in Storyboard, that would be much simple

Comment: this Complex design not working with Xcode 8

Comment: Please show what is happening with the code you have.

Comment: @Paulw11 my  code working fine need to simplify it